# Can I write a singular object after "are"?

Tags: sentence-construction, plural-forms

I have this sentence in a technology book.

> Decision tables are a convenient way to organize information in a systematic manner.

I wonder if that sentence is correct, since the author has used `a` after `are`

#### Update

My confusion happens because `are` is for plurals not single

Comment: Why do you think it is wrong?

Comment: @user3169 because `are` is using for pruler not single

Comment: The bigger issue is understanding what parts of the sentence influences the verb form (and article usage). Your question should say more about your current understanding on this, as it is a bigger issue than can be covered in a few phrases.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not only correct, it's actually very common to use "are a" in English. Here **are a** few examples:

1. These criminals are a threat to society
2. I married my girlfriend, because marriages are a good way to show people you love them
3. The gifts he gave you are a good reason to think he likes you!

These example work because *every* criminal I was talking about was a threat to society, *every* marriage is a good way to show people you love them, and *all* the gifts together are a good reason for the girl to think the boy likes her. When we talk about things as a collection serving a specific purpose, "are a" is a very common construct.

Comment: You might mention that are vs. is relates to the subject and not to the argument. "When we talk about things as a collection serving a specific purpose" That's a good summary of why this makes sense.